# I'm unable to override justify-content

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to override justify-content CSS with specificity, but it doesn't seem to work. In my example, I would like for the `2` to be at the top of the div instead of in the center, but for some reason my `justify-content:baseline` doesn't override the `center` value.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:grid;
}
  .flex-container div {
    display:flex;
    height:50px;
    justify-content:center;
  }
  .flex-container div.baseline {
    justify-content:baseline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="baseline">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `baseline` is not a valid value for `justify-content`. Do you mean `align-items: baseline;`?

Comment: Weird, when I enter `justify-content` into Chrome dev tools, `baseline` comes up as one of the pre-populated options, and when I set it to `baseline` and turn off `center`, it gives me the desired result, but I suppose that's just because I turned center off.

Comment: well it doesn't in my Chrome, maybe you need to update?

Comment: [This in Chrome 67.0.3396.62](https://imgur.com/4ExWWd8) which it says is latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing justify-content with align-items.

The `justify-content` property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

The align-items property specifies the default alignment for items inside the flexible container.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

This is how I think you should use it.

```css
.flex-container {
  display:grid;
}
  .flex-container div {
    display:flex;
    height:50px;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .flex-container div.baseline {
    align-items:flex-start;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="baseline">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, really odd that Chrome suggests `baseline` when you enter `justify-content` into the dev tools.

Comment: *...`justify-content` is for horizontally aligning text in a div while `align-items` is for vertically aligning text in a div.* That is incorrect and misleading information.